# Ubuntu 14.04 does not save screen resolution

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 with Gnome. Every time I restart my computer I have to manually set the screen resolution to a lower one.

Why it is not being saved automatically?

Some outputs:

```
$ lspci

00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor
Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 12)
```

```
$ uname -a

Linux mediaserver 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29
20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ ls /usr/bin/*session

/usr/bin/gnome-session
```

```
$ echo $DESKTOP_SESSION

gnome-fallback
```

[/var/log/Xorg.0.log](http://textuploader.com/ddvmh)

Comment: Just to confirm...The initial resolution is 1920x1080 and you switch it back manually to 1280x720?

Comment: @mmmint correct, that is the change I have to do every time I turn on my pc

Comment: Have you tried setting xrandr changes persistently in `~/.xprofile` or `xorg.conf`?

Comment: @mmmint I did not have a xorg.conf, so I created this one and after reboot changes are saved. Thanks!

`Section "Monitor"
    Identifier    "Monitor0"
    Modeline "1280x720_60.00"   74.50  1280 1344 1472 1664  720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Card0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Modes       "1280x1024_60.00" "1024x768_60.00"
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier    "Card0"
    Driver        "i915"
EndSection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed after creating the */etc/X11/xorg.conf* file with the following content:

```
Section "Monitor" Identifier "Monitor0" Modeline "1280x720_60.00"
    74.50 1280 1344 1472 1664 720 723 728 748 -hsync +vsync
EndSection
Section "Screen" 
    Identifier "Screen0"  
    Device "Card0"  
    Monitor "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"  
        Modes "1280x1024_60.00" "1024x768_60.00" 
    EndSubSection
EndSection 
Section "Device" 
    Identifier "Card0" 
    Driver "i915" 
EndSection
```